# Converting JSON String with multiple objects into class instances

Tags: java, json, jackson

**How do I convert a Json String with multiple Objects to java objects:**

EDIT:It would seem unlikely that it would work, yet would this create 2 class instances of class **Statement**:

```
String JsonStr = "{\"bills\":[{\"amount\":\"13\",\"billId\":\"billid3\"}] ,\"bills\":[{\"amount\":\"155\",\"billId\":\"billid4\"}]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Statement obj = mapper.readValue(JsonStr, obj.class);
```

If not, how do I write the code for a program that receives a JSON String with multiple unique objects of the same type(bank statement), and create the appropriate number of java object instances of it?
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the code snippet? Your `String` isn't surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry i didn't place much attention on that part.. Considering those 3 lines are java runnable

Comment: You could potentially get array of bills. Do you expect something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the json string you provided should be like

> "{\"bills\":[{\"amount\":\"13\",\"billId\":\"billid3\"}
>   ,{\"amount\":\"155\",\"billId\":\"billid4\"}]}"

If this is the case, you can use the solution below:

Create two classes **Bill.java** and **TestObject.java** as follows:

**Bill.java**

```
public class Bill {
    private double amount;
    private String billId;
    /**
     * @return the amount
     */
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    /**
     * @param amount the amount to set
     */
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    /**
     * @return the billId
     */
    public String getBillId() {
        return billId;
    }
    /**
     * @param billId the billId to set
     */
    public void setBillId(String billId) {
        this.billId = billId;
    }

}
```

**TestObject.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class TestObject {

    private List<Bill> bills;

    /**
     * @return the bills
     */
    public List<Bill> getBills() {
        return bills;
    }

    /**
     * @param bills the bills to set
     */
    public void setBills(List<Bill> bills) {
        this.bills = bills;
    }

}
```

Here is the main program to test the code.

**Test.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonStr = "{\"bills\":[{\"amount\":\"13\",\"billId\":\"billid3\"} ,{\"amount\":\"155\",\"billId\":\"billid4\"}]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            TestObject testObject = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, TestObject.class);
            System.out.print(testObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your code made me realize how Jackson's mapper automatically takes care of object creation. Although it seems on my end there still seems to be an error of the type:"Unrecognized field "bills" (Class sample.TestObject), not marked as ignorable". If you know how to solve this it would be greatly appreciated1

Answer (score 1):

I have used gson-2.2.2.jar.

Please find code given below :

**Bill.java**

```
public class Bill
{
    private double  billAmount;

    private String  billId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Bill bill = null;
        List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<Bill>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            bill = new Bill();
            bill.setBillAmount(100 + (i + 1));
            bill.setBillId("bill_id_" + (i + 1));
            bills.add(bill);
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(bills, new TypeToken<List<Bill>>()
        {}.getType());
        System.out.println(json);

        Type mapType = new TypeToken<List<Bill>>()
        {}.getType();
        List<Bill> billsRetrieved = new Gson().fromJson(json, mapType);
        for (Bill bill2 : billsRetrieved)
        {
            System.out.println(bill2.getBillId());
        }
    }
}
```

**OutPut :**

```
[
   {
      "billAmount":101.0,
      "billId":"bill_id_1"
   },
   {
      "billAmount":102.0,
      "billId":"bill_id_2"
   },
   {
      "billAmount":103.0,
      "billId":"bill_id_3"
   },
   {
      "billAmount":104.0,
      "billId":"bill_id_4"
   },
   {
      "billAmount":105.0,
      "billId":"bill_id_5"
   }
]
```

bill_id_1
bill_id_2
bill_id_3
bill_id_4
bill_id_5

Please revert in case you need further explanation.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I wanted, but introduced me to Gson which seems very useful. I would surely make use of it!